# replace initial number in MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a huge list of phone number.. all start with 09. So I want to replace all the Initial 09 into 959... There maybe 09 inside the phone no. But I don't want to change it. I only want to change Initial 09 into 959.. 
Please help....

- 09111222333 into 959111222333
- 09110922233 into 959110922233

This is what I try! but not working

> Select Replace('09*','09','959')
>   From MyTable;

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using an update query. You only want to replace the first occurrence of '09' so you need to tell the replace function.

Try replace([yourfield],'09','959',1,1) which tells Access to only replace the first occurrence of the string '09' in [yourfield] starting from the first character.

As pointed out in the comments, this solution assumes all your phone numbers start with a leading '09'. If they do not you'll have to work with an if clause:

iif(left([yourfield],2)='09',replace([yourfield],'09','959',1,1),[yourfield])

Comment: As a note this means that if you got numbers that don't have a leading 09 you will replace another occurrence, if there is one (likely). So 555111109 would still be replaced.

Comment: True, but the poster indicated that all phone numbers start with a '09'. I'll clarify my answer though.

Comment: To avoid problems with numbers not starting with 09 one could of course run the Replace() only on the leftmost part of the string, so something like Replace(Left([yourfield], 2), '09', '959'). [Code written free-hand, not tested]

Comment: replace [yourfield],'09','959',1,1 .... What should I put in [yourfield]???. I am just a beginner. So I don't know much about this.

Comment: [yourfield] is just a placeholder for the name of your column holding the phone numbers.